# how to avoid memory wastage when storing UTF-8 characters (8 bit) in Java character (16 bit). two in one?

Tags: java, memory, utf-8, byte, 8-bit

I'm afraid I have a question on a detail of a rather oversaturated topic, I searched aroudn a lot, but couldn't find a clear answer to that specific obvious -imho- important, problem:

When converting byte[] to String using UTF-8, each byte (8bit) becomes a 8 bit character encoded by UTF-8, but each UTF-8 character is saved as a 16 bit character in java. Is that correct? 
If yes, this means, that each stupid java character only uses the first 8 bits, and consumes double the memory? Is that correct too? I wonder how this wasteful behaviour is acceptable..

Isn't there some trick to have a pseudo String that is 8 bit?  Would that actually result in less memory consumption?
Or maybe, is there a way to store >two< 8bit characters in one java 16bit character to avoid this memory waste?

thanks for any deconfusing answers...

EDIT:
hi, thanks everybody for answering. I was aware of the variable-length property of UTF-8. However, since my source is byte which is 8 bit, I understood (apparently wrongly) that it needs only 8-bit UTF-8 words. Is UTF-8 conversion actually saving the strange symbols that you see when on the CLI you do "cat somebinary" ? I thought UTF-8 was just somehow used to map each of the possible 8bit words of byte to one particular 8 bit word of UTF-8. Wrong? I thought about using Base64 but it's bad because it uses only 7 bit..

questions reformulated: is there a smarter way to convert byte to something String? 
May favorite was to just cast byte[] to char[], but then I still have 16bit words.

additional use case info:

I'm adapting [Jedis](http://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) (java client for the NoSQL Redis) as the  "primitive storage layer" for hypergraphDB. So, jedis is a database for another "database".
My problem is that I have to feed jedis with byte[] data all the time, but internally, >Redis< (the actual server)  is dealing only with "binary safe" Strings. Since Redis is written in C, a char is 8 bit long, AFAIK not ASCIII which is 7 bit. In Jedis however, java world, every character is 16 bit long internally. I don't understand this code (yet), but I suppose jedis then converts this java 16 bit strings to a Redis conforming 8 bit string (([here][3]). It says it extends FilterOutputStream. My hope is to bypass the byte[] <-> string conversion altogether and use that Filteroutputstream...?  )

now I wonder: if I had to interconvert byte[] and String all the time, with datasizes ranging from very small to potentially very big, isn't there a huge waste of memory to have each 8 bit character passed around as 16bit within java?

Comment: You are aware that some UTF-8 characters are 2, 3, or 4 bytes, right? The whole world doesn't use ASCII.

Comment: hi, thanks everybody for answering. I was aware of the variable-length property of UTF-8. However, since my source is byte which is 8 bit, I understood that it needs only 8-bit UTF-8 words. Isn't that so? Is UTF-8 conversion actually saving the strange symbols that you see when on the CLI you do "cat somebinary" ? I thought UTF-8 was just somehow used to map each of the possible 8bit words of byte to one 8 bit word of UTF-8. Wrong? I thought about using Base64 but it's bad because it uses only 7 bit..

Comment: UTF-16 is also a variable-width encoding, just like UTF-8.  It just uses bigger code units.

Comment: What would be bad about casting two bytes to one char ?

Comment: What would be bad is that a character comprises 21 bits.

Comment: You could Huffman‐encode it so that the most common code points occupy the fewest bits, and vice versa. Every document would thus require a different preambulatory lookup dictionary mapping bits to code points. This would be a false efficiency.

Comment: hmm? why is a character 21 bit not 16bit / multiple of 8bit? remember, I only want to store bytes efficently, I dont care about special characters.

Comment: Your statement contains a false premise: there is no such thing as a “special character”; code points are either legal or not. Provided both are legal code points, code points U+XXXXX and U+YYYYYY are equally non‑special. The only *specialness* would be inferred from an inverse frequency analysis, and that would be a Huffman game of exceedingly limited applicability. Unicode comprises the ordinals between 0 and 0x1FFFFF, although not all those are valid for interchange. It is by that measure that a character comprises 21 bits; anything less than 21 bits is *ipso facto* less than a character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Isn't there some trick to have a pseudo String that is 8 bit?

yes, make sure you have an up to date version of Java. ;)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

> -XX:+UseCompressedStrings     Use a byte[] for Strings which can be represented as pure ASCII. (Introduced in Java 6 Update 21 Performance Release)

EDIT: This option doesn't work in Java 6 update 22 and is not on by default in Java 6 update 24. Note: it appears this option may slow performance by about 10%.

The following program

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        sb.append(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        test(sb, j >= 2);
}

private static void test(StringBuilder sb, boolean print) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    forceGC();
    long free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    long size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        final String s = "" + sb + i;
        strings.add(s);
        size += s.length();
    }
    forceGC();
    long used = free - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    if (print)
        System.out.println("Bytes per character is " + (double) used / size);
}

private static void forceGC() {
    try {
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(250);
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(250);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Prints this by default

```
Bytes per character is 2.0013668655941212
Bytes per character is 2.0013668655941212
Bytes per character is 2.0013606946433575
Bytes per character is 2.0013668655941212
```

with the option `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`

```
Bytes per character is 1.0014671435440285
Bytes per character is 1.0014671435440285
Bytes per character is 1.0014609725932648
Bytes per character is 1.0014671435440285
```

Comment: Peter, that is *very* interesting, so thank you! I say this because I have long been frustrated by the um, finality, of Java’s `String` class, combined with how it is tied into `String` literals in the language. This makes it impossible to use proper OO techniques for any sort of improved or variant strings. You have just shown one such use; several of mine involve posit strings composed either of code point sequences, or also grapheme sequences. I did not know about `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings`; its existence suggests it might be possible to do other such, although perhaps not portably.

Comment: very nice! if I save 50% of memory, having more memory should overcompensate a performance drop of 10%. thanks

Comment: This shows another potential use for a user‐defined `String` datatype in the Java language. One could alter the underlying memory allocation from variable‐width UTF‐16 to variable‐width UTF‐8 or to fixed‐width UTF‐32, according to one’s purpose and code‐point distribution. These could be further compessed as an implementational detail — at a time–space trade‐off. All it’d take is to enhance the Java `String` definition to admit anything conforming to a **“uniform code‐point interface”.** String literals could be controlled by a lexically scoped compiler directive (*pragma*) per source unit.

Comment: My long comment shows why ASCII is insufficient for even pure English text: I employed not merely 3 distinct types of quotation marks (`\p{Quotation_Mark}`), but also 4 distinct types of hyphens and dashes (`\p{Dash}`). You probably don’t even notice which are which, but that’s ok: they’re still needed to render everyday English correctly.

Comment: @tchrist, In England, they use the £ in every day English. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you have the UTF-8 part wrong: UTF-8 is a variable-length multibyte encoding, so there are valid characters 1-4 bytes in length (in other words, some UTF-8 characters are 8-bit, some are 16-bit, some are 24-bit, and some are 32-bit). Although the 1-byte characters take up 8 bits, there are many more multibyte characters. If you only had 1-byte characters, it would only allow you to have 256 different characters in total (a.k.a. "Extended ASCII"); that may be sufficient for 90% of use in English (my *naïve* guesstimate), but would bite you in the ass as soon as you even *think* of anything beyond that subset (see the word naïve - English, yet can't be written just with ASCII).

So, although UTF-16 (which Java uses) looks wasteful, it's actually not. Anyway, unless you're on a very limited embedded system (in which case, what you're doing there with Java?), trying to trim down the strings is pointless microoptimization.

For a slightly longer introduction to character encodings, see e.g. this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: *[mouth drops, stunned silence]* So you've shown him something else, which is wrong but *appears* to work, and which is *very* hard to unlearn? I'm shocked, *shocked*!

Comment: thanks piskvor for answering. I'm reading your link now.. I the 256 possible words of byte just get mapped to 256 "characters" of 8 bit only UTF-8. So now, I'm even more convinced that it's a really a stupid thing, this conversion between byte[] <--> string... there isn't a better way??

Comment: Java does not use UCS-2.  It uses UTF-16.  This is easily demonstrated: the regex engine treats any Unicode character as `.`, no matter how many code units it occupies.

Comment: @user703862: Not really. In UTF-8, only the characters 0-127 are single-byte; anything beyond that is multi-byte. Although all encodings of Unicode (UTF-8, UCS-2 and others) have their shortcomings, yes, this is the best commonly supported way.

Comment: UCS-2 is not a Unicode encoding, because it cannot represent all Unicode code points (apart from those guaranteed to be illegal for interchange). The UTF-* encodings, in contrast, *do* do that. I happen to prefer both UTF-8 and UTF-32, depending on what I’m doing, over UTF-16, but that’s too complicated to get into here.

Comment: @tchrist: Sorry for the misinformation. For the sake of completeness: "UCS-2 was superseded by UTF-16 in version 2.0 of the Unicode standard in July 1996". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS_2

Comment: @Piskvor, no problem. Part of my de‑facto job involves educating my Java‐lingo’d co‐workers about differences between UCS‑2 and UTF‑16. Much of the problem stems from old documentation and “simplified versions of reality”. Java v1 debuted in ’95, Unicode v2 in ’96, but it was by then  already deemed politically too late to fix the Java `char` bug. Other factors collude to continue the confusion (eg, interfaces deficient at handling code points), but none is worse than the cognitive dissonance resulting from a Java `char` or `Character` being too small to hold a Unicode code point.

Answer (score 2):

> When converting byte[] to String using UTF-8, each byte (8bit) becomes a 8 bit character encoded by UTF-8

No. When converting `byte[]` to `String` using UTF-8, each [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) **sequence** of 1-6 bytes is converted into a UTF-16 **sequence** of 1-2 16-bit characters.

In almost all cases, *worldwide*, this UTF-16 sequence contains a single character.

In Western Europe and North America, for *most* text, only 8 bits of this 16-bit character are used. However, if you have a Euro sign, you'll need more than 8 bits.

For more information, see [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Or [Joel Spolsky's article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: +1 Indeed. Just a minor nitpick: the above only holds if by "Western Europe" you mean "UK" and by "North America" you mean "USA". Otherwise, you'll get the French `é`, the Spanish `Ñ`, the German `ß`, which are all multibyte in UTF-8.

Comment: @Piskvor: Curly quotes and proper dashes and hyphens — both necessary for writing English properly — all take multiple code units in UTF-8.  As for the UK, Welsh also uses letters outside the ASCII range. Plus anybody who writes *resume* on their *résumé* automatically flunks.

Comment: @tchrist: Quite so - but 1) note that @Anon writes "for most text", and 2) these have been (unfairly) dismissed for years as "unnecessary nitpicking, why can't you just use `-` instead of your fancy e[mn] dashes, yada yada", so I wanted to present examples where the necessity is clear.

Comment: @Piskvor - I never said that they weren't. I did say that most western characters would occupy the *lower 8 bits of a 16-bit Java character*. And although I haven't checked, I believe that all the characters that you mention are ISO-8859-1, so this is true. The punctuation symbols that *tchrist* mentions, however, do not fit in that space.

Comment: @Anon: I'm not trying to contradict you, sorry if I didn't make myself clear. As for ISO-8859-*, those were a temporary hack in the vein of "this will only go to people who speak *my* language"; ever tried converting between them? Fun fun fun (not).

Comment: ISO 8859‑15, sometimes called **Latin‑9,** works somewhat better for some Western languages than does the original ISO 8859‑1, **Latin‑1,** because it includes **œ** and **Œ** needed for properly writing such words as French *œuf* (U+153) and *Œuvre de secours aux enfants* (U+152) and the ᴀʟʟᴄᴀᴘs version of *Pierre Louÿs*, since *LOUŸS* requires **Ÿ** at U+178. However, it does such things at a cost that is unacceptable to certain other languages. No 8-bit repertoire suffices to write modern text, especially but only English. Unicode solves all those problems; please do not reinstantiate them.

Comment: @tchrist - huh? Was that last comment meant to refer to my post, one of the comments, or something completely different? Perhaps I'm overreacting, but my answer *has nothing to do with comparing character sets*. It was meant to correct the OP's misconception of why Java uses 16 bits for a `char`. If you believe that I did that poorly, you are of course free to edit or downvote. If you believe that I have said something factually incorrect, please correct me. But first, please verify that you're correcting something that I actually said.

Comment: @Anon, oh I was just riffing on why ISO 8859-1 is no panacea, that’s all. No ding intended.  Anybody who helps “dis–mis‐inform” the general public about the wherefores and therefores relating to Java’s somewhat sub‐obvious character set‐up earns my appreciation — and upvote. The only nitpicky nuance I might touch up is that *any* 1‑ or 2‑charunit UTF‑16 sequence representing a single Unicode code point *always* maps to a single character “worldwide” — if and only if you equate code points to user‐perceived characters, which is a slightly dodgy assumption but better than many others.

Answer (score 2):

Java stores all it's "chars" internally as two bytes representations of the value. However, they aren't stored the same as UTF-8. For example, the max value supported is "\uFFFF" (hex FFFF, dec 65536), or 11111111 11111111 binary (two bytes) - but this would be a 3 byte Unicode character on disk.

The only possible wastage is for genuinely 'single' byte characters in memory (most ASCII 'language' characters actually fit in 7bits). When the characters are written to disk, they'll be in the specified encoding anyway (so UTF-8 single byte characters will only occupy one byte).

The only place it makes a difference is in the JVM heap. However, you'd have to have thousands and thousands of 8-bit characters to notice any real difference in Java heap usage - which would be far outweighed by all the extra (hacky) processing you've done.

A million-odd 8-bit characters in RAM is only 'wasting' about 1 MiB anyway...

Comment: +1, minor nitpick: There's no such thing as "stored Unicode", there are however several Unicode encodings (mapping between the somewhat abstract *characters* and their *byte representations*)

Comment: Yes, that should probably read "aren't stored the same as UTF-8". \uFFFF is 11101111 10111111 10111111 on disk (UTF-8).

Comment: thanks mikaveli. My only worry is JVM heap memory. I'm dealing with lots of byte[] which I have to pack in "Strings" in an memory efficient manner.

Comment: That's understandable, but I wouldn't want to give up Java's native Unicode support - there are lots of other workarounds available to control the amount of byte[] / characters in memory (streams, persistence etc etc).

Comment: I wouldn’t want to “give up” Java’s “native Unicode support”; however, I’d want to make it actually work. It’s a bit begrudged and clunky right now, making it **far too easy to do the wrong thing** and too hard to do the right one. Unicode isn’t just assigning characters to ordinals; that’s UCS. Unicode is also a rich collection of behaviors, almost none of which Java is up to speed at. It doesn’t do full case mapping at all, and though it provides for UAX#15, it neglects UTS#10, UAX#14, UTS#18, UAX#11, UAX#29, and indeed most of the crucial UAX#44. **Java supports Unicode poorly.**

Answer (score 1):

> *Redis* (the actual server) is dealing only with "binary safe" Strings.

I take this to mean that you can use arbitrary octet sequences for the keys/values. If you can use any C `char` sequence without thought to character encoding, then the equivalent in Java is the `byte` type.

Strings in Java are implicitly `UTF-16`. I mean, you could stick arbitrary numbers in there, but the intent of the class is to represent Unicode character data. Methods that do `byte`-to-`char` transformations perform transcoding operations from a known encoding to UTF-16.

**If Jedis treats keys/values as UTF-8, then it will not support every value that Redis supports.** Not every byte sequence is valid UTF-8, so the encoding can't be used for binary safe strings.

---

*Whether UTF-8 or UTF-16 consumes more memory depends on the data - the euro symbol (€) for example consumes three bytes in UTF-8 and only two in UTF-16.*

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I wrote my own little implementation of a byte[] <-> String interconverter, that works by casting every 2 bytes in 1 char. It's roughly 30-40% faster and consumes (possibly less than) half the memory of the Java standard way: new String(somebyte)  and someString.getBytes().

However, it is incompatible with existing string encoded bytes or byte encoded strings. Furthermore, it is not safe to call the method from different JVMs on shared data.

https://github.com/ib84/castriba

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is this what you want:

```
// Store them into the 16 bit datatype.
char c1_8bit = 'a';
char c2_8bit = 'h';
char two_chars = (c1_8bit << 8) + c2_8bit;

// extract them
char c1_8bit = two_chars >> 8;
char c2_8bit = two_chars & 0xFF;
```

Of course this trick only works with ASCII chars (chars in the range [0-255]). Why? 
Because you want to store your chars this way:
`xxxx xxxx  yyyy yyyy` with `x` is char 1 and `y` is char 2. So this means you have only 8 bit per char. And what is the biggest integer you can make with 8 bit? Answer: 255

`255` = `0000 0000 1111 1111` (8 bit). And when you are using a char > 255, then you will have this:
`256` = `0000 0001 0000 0000` (more than 8 bit), which doesn't fit in the 8 bit you provide for 1 char.

Plus: Keep in mind Java is a language, developed by clever people. They knew what they where doing. *Thrust the Java API*

Comment: Seemingly clever, but try to do this with these two characters: `çé`. Oh, they're not 8-bit, are they? Congratulations, you now have a weird mess in `two_chars` with no way to extract the original characters. (Interesting how everyone thinks that ASCII should be enough for everyone, even when they meet characters outside ASCII, every day)

Comment: @Piskvor: I said I know it won't work with chars out of the range [0-255]. But if he knows what he is doing, and his application only uses ASCII chars, this is what he wants...

Comment: If the Java folks were so clever, why would they create a `char` datatype that isn’t big enough to hold a character?  Remember: *“int* is the new *char*.”

Comment: "if his application only uses ASCII chars" - that is possible but not very likely. In such case, yours would be a valid way to do it (although I'd still think that there are better ways to conserve space, such as Huffman coding).

Comment: thanks for that answer. I acually don't care at all about characters. I just want to pack byte in string efficiently. So yes, byte should be [0-255] maybe I have to use Shift operators as you did. Your hint remembered me that some peoples just casted byte to strings. So now I'm trying to cast two byte into one char.